# Why do I get ValueError("There must be at least one expected method") from mox, when I know that the function I've mocked out is getting called?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mox

I'm using mox to stub out an email-sending function in my code. I want to verify that the function is called N times, with a certain set of params each time.

Mox is raising ValueError("There must be at least one expected method") as if the function calls that I've stubbed out are not happening, but they actually seem to be happening.

Watching my logs, I can see the functions being called and see all the log messages / updates in my DB that tell me the code being tested is in fact working. I also have 14 other unit tests verifying that, so I'm confident this is a problem with the test rather than the underlying code.

Here is my test:

```
class MyTestSuite(mox.MoxTestBase):
    def test_my_send_function(self):
        self.mox.StubOutWithMock(module_path, "my_send_function")
        for state in SEQUENCE: # defined elsewhere, assume 5 states in sequence
            module_path.my_send_function(to_email_address, subject, IgnoreArg())
    self.mox.ReplayAll()

    module_path.my_send_function_parent() # loops over the 5 states in SEQUENCE and calls my_send_function()

    # Verify() and UnsetStubs() are done automatically because I subclasses MoxTestBase
```

Why is mox saying the calls never happened when they are? I could not find anything about this in the mox docs or elsewhere here on SO.

Comment: If your real function is being called, because you see it in the logs, it probably means your didn't really mock the function. I thought when you mock something it wont execute the real code of the function but do nothing and only check if its being called.  maybe your module path is wrong?

Comment: I was wondering about the namespacing, so I am mocking / calling the function with the full path to the function rather than by name only.